# Majoration of spectral radius using L1 norm of columns and lines

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, denote $\rho(A)$ its spectral radius, the maximum of the modulus of its eigenvalues. Denote $L_k = \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{kj}|$ and $C_k = \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ik}|$ the $L^1$ norms of its lines and columns, respectively.

Using an eigenvector and its largest coordinate, one can show that $\rho(A)\leq \max\limits_k L_k$. And using $A^T$, one also has $\rho(A)\leq \max\limits_k C_k$.

Is it true that $\rho(A)^2 \leq \max\limits_{k} L_k C_k$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. Let $L_k'=L_k-|a_{kk}|$, the $k$-th deleted absolute row sum of $A$. Define $C_k'$ analogously. [Ostrowski’s theorem](https://planetmath.org/ostrowskitheorem) states that for any $\alpha\in[0,1]$, the spectrum of $A$ lies inside the following union of Ostrowski sets:
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^n\left\{z\in\mathbb C: |z-a_{kk}|\le \left(L_k'\right)^\alpha\left(C_k'\right)^{1-\alpha}\right\}.
$$
(See Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, 2/e, pp. 413-414, theorem 6.4.1.)
In particular, when $\alpha=\frac12$, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho(A)^2
&\le\max_k\left(|a_{kk}|+\sqrt{L_k' C_k'}\right)^2\\
&=\max_k\left\langle\left(\sqrt{|a_{kk}|},\sqrt{L_k'}\right),\ \left(\sqrt{|a_{kk}|},\sqrt{C_k'}\right)\right\rangle^2 \\
&\le\max_k\left\|\left(\sqrt{|a_{kk}|},\sqrt{L_k'}\right)\right\|^2\ \left\|\left(\sqrt{|a_{kk}|},\sqrt{C_k'}\right)\right\|^2 \\
&=\max_kL_kC_k.
\end{aligned}
$$